# XMODMAP 14.04 vs 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, xmodmap

Have used Xmodmap successfully with 14.04 starting up with startup app.

Not so with 16.04.  It does work when I activate it directly. Does anyone know of any change  from 14.04 to 16.04 that causes this problem. Tried different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

open gnome-session-properties. add command and name. desktop file will be created in ~/.config/autostart.

remenber: use **absolute path** in the command line, eg /home/xxx/.Xmodmap. never use '~' as your home dir.